# Center String on CGPoint

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, cgpoint

the marker's that I'm trying to draw on the endpoints of the line are a little off the center of the point, I feel like I'm using the right calculations, but they still seem a bit off. Here's a screenshot of the simulator:

[image: Screenshot]

Here's the code that I used:

```
UIFont *markerF = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:40];
NSDictionary *markerA = @{NSFontAttributeName:markerF, NSForegroundColorAttributeName:  [UIColor blueColor]};
NSString *markerT = @"+";

CGPoint markerC = CGPointMake(p1.x, p1.y);
CGSize markerS = [markerT sizeWithAttributes:markerA];
CGRect markerR = CGRectMake(markerC.x - (markerS.width / 2.0), markerC.y - (markerS.height / 2.0), markerS.width, markerS.height);
[markerT drawInRect:markerR withAttributes:markerA];
```

How can I make so that it also adds one of these markers at the end, too?

Thanks

Comment: Why use a string for the + marker? Why not draw two little lines to make the +?

Comment: I'm thinking that as long as the + is centered on the point then it should work fine, I haven't thought of your method, and honestly I don't know how to implement it

Comment: You already know how to draw lines. Therefore you should know how to draw two lines for each + symbol.

Comment: Maddy's right - what you're probably seeing is font characteristics - it's going to draw the '+' as text and that means it's going to adjust for baseline, ascent and descent.  You'd do best to calculate two lines for your plus sign and draw them yourself.

Comment: alright, I'll try it out. I will post the answer when I get it to work. thanks.

Comment: @Alex can u share the code for displaying number (505.85) in centre between two points.. It will be helpful.. Thanks

Comment: @Dave here's the code: [http://pastebin.com/GbxZXA7F](http://pastebin.com/GbxZXA7F) One of the issues with this code is that when the line is flat the string will overlap with the line, instead of moving above/below the line.